# Getting segmentation fault while creating reader and writer threads inside a infinite while loop on random condition

Tags: c, multithreading, gdb, pthreads

I am trying to create reader and writer threads (5 each) inside an infinite while loop randomly. The writers should wait until all readers are done executing. I am using mutex and condition variables for this purpose.

```
// Global variables
int readerCount=0, writerCount=0, sharedVariable=1001;

pthread_mutex_t m = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t read_cond = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t write_cond = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
```

The reader threads run the below function

```
void *readShared(void* param)
{
    int shVariable, readers; //To copy and print global variables locally

    pthread_mutex_lock(&m);

        readerCount++;
        while(readerCount > 1)
        {
            pthread_cond_wait(&read_cond, &m);
        }
        readerCount--;
        readers = readerCount;
        shVariable = sharedVariable;

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&m);

    printf("[Reader]:  Value in shared Variable = %d\n", shVariable);
    printf("Other \"Reader\" threads present = %d\n", readers);

    pthread_mutex_lock(&m);

        if(readerCount > 0)
        {
            pthread_cond_signal(&read_cond);
        }
        else if(writerCount > 0)
        {
            pthread_cond_signal(&write_cond);
        }

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&m);
}
```

The writer threads run below function:

```
void *writeShared(void *valueToWrite)
{
        //To copy and print global variables
    int value = *(int *)(valueToWrite), readers, shVariable;

    pthread_mutex_lock(&m);

        writerCount++;
        while(readerCount > 0 || writerCount > 1)
        {
            pthread_cond_wait(&write_cond, &m);
        }
        sharedVariable = value;
        readers = readerCount;
        shVariable = sharedVariable;
        writerCount--;

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&m);

    printf("[Writer]:  Value in shared Variable = %d\n", shVariable);
    printf("Value to write = %d\n", value);
    printf("Other \"Reader\" threads present = %d\n", readers);


    pthread_mutex_lock(&m);

        if(readerCount > 0)
        {
            pthread_cond_signal(&read_cond);
        }
        else if(writerCount > 0)
        {
            pthread_cond_signal(&write_cond);
        }

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&m);
}
```

The main function:

```
int main()
{
    pthread_t readers[5], writers[5];
    int readerIndex=0, writerIndex=0;
    while(1)
    {
        if(5 == readerIndex && 5 == writerIndex)
        {
            break;
        }
        if(rand() % 2)
        {
            if(readerIndex < 5)
            {
                pthread_create(&readers[readerIndex++], NULL, readShared, NULL);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if(writerIndex < 5)
            {
                pthread_create(&writers[writerIndex++], NULL, writeShared, (void*)((rand() % 1000) + 100));
            }
        }
    }
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        pthread_join(readers[i], NULL);
        pthread_join(writers[i], NULL);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I tried running with gdb and obtained following:

```
Starting program: /home/abhijeet/threads/readWrite 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".

[New Thread 0x7ffff77c4700 (LWP 3232)]
[Reader]:  Value in shared Variable = 1001
Other "Reader" threads present = 0

[New Thread 0x7ffff6fc3700 (LWP 3233)]
[Thread 0x7ffff77c4700 (LWP 3232) exited]

[New Thread 0x7ffff67c2700 (LWP 3234)]
[Reader]:  Value in shared Variable = 1001
Other "Reader" threads present = 0

[New Thread 0x7ffff5fc1700 (LWP 3235)]
[Thread 0x7ffff67c2700 (LWP 3234) exited]

Thread 3 "readWrite" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.

[Switching to Thread 0x7ffff6fc3700 (LWP 3233)]
0x000055555555494a in writeShared (valueToWrite=0x36d) at PriorityReadWrite.c:13
13      int value = *(int *)(valueToWrite), readers, shVariable;
```

Comment: `int value = *(int *)(valueToWrite)` should be `int value = (int *)(valueToWrite), readers`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

> `pthread_create(&writers[writerIndex++], NULL, writeShared, (void*)((rand() % 1000) + 100));`

passes a random integer between 100 and 1099 to the `writeShared` function as an argument. In the particular invocation that you debugged with GDB, the random value was `0x36d`, or `877`.

This line:

> `int value = *(int *)(valueToWrite)`

takes passed integer and interprets it as an *address* of an integer (which it is not), resulting in the segmentation fault.

To fix this, you need to either pass in an address of an actual integer (create an array of `int valueToWrite[5]` in `main`, and pass `&valueToWrite[writerIndex]` to `pthread_create` (be careful to increment `writerIndex` *after* you've created the thread).

Alternatively, you can fix the `writeShared` to expect an integer instead of an address:

```
int value = (int)valueToWrite;
```

Comment: regarding: *passes a random integer between 0 and 1000 to the writeShared function as an argument.*  Actually this passes a value 100 ... 1099 to the writeShared function